# Javascript isn't working in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

**How to move user forward & backward when user is logged in & when he is logged out ,he won't be able to go it's home page .**

I'm creating a website in ASP.NET (Framework 4.0). I had used Javascript in Masterpage head section. Code as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward(-1);
    </script>
```

And on page load (masterpage ) i had written code for cache.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

My user gets login to his home page (i.e frmUserHome.aspx ) when clicks on next page (i.e frmUserService.aspx) he is redirected to service page ,but he is not able to go back to it's home page (i.e frmUserHome.aspx). This all is happening beacause of javascript written in master page.

Comment: unconditional `window.history.forward(-1)` will not behave nicely... Please make sure your post provides clear [MCVE] and not just random pieces of code. Also try to edit "My question" part to sound like a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below Javascript code may help you...

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
    function preventBack(){window.history.forward();} 
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0); 
    window.onunload=function(){null}; 
    </script>
```

use this code in a page where you don't want to go back...

Comment: I have added this code in Master page head section , but it's not working. I have replace my code with your code & rebuild it. I am facing same problem .

Comment: @Ronp It shouldn't be in master page. Just add this code in the page where you want to restrict the go back functionality.